# Получить высоту и ширину картинки с бэкграунда блока или src img

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

как получить высоту и шиирину картинки установленной на бэкграунде элемента или в img?

в моем случае на бэкграунде

блока:

```
 <div class="myuclick" style="background-image: url(./img/m1.jpg);"></div>
```

пробую так получить:

```
 $(document).on('click','.myuclick',function () {

    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = $(this).css('background-image');
            var height = newImg.height;
            var width = newImg.width;
            console.log('Ширина:' + width + ' Высота:' + height);

});
```

но увы у меня выдает в лог что и ширина и высота 0 
этот вариант я подсмотрел в одном примере и сделал немного под себя, скажите пожалуйста в чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var height;
var width;
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.onload = () => {
  height = newImg.height;
  width = newImg.width;
  console.log('Ширина:' + width + ' Высота:' + height);
};
var src = $(this).css('background-image');
src = src.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
newImg.src = src;
```

```js
function getBgImageDimensions(el) {
  var newImg = new Image();
  newImg.onload = () => {
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    console.log('Ширина:' + width + ' Высота:' + height);
  };
  var src = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundImage;
  src = src.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
  newImg.src = src; 
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onclick="getBgImageDimensions(this)"></div>
```

Comment: А обрезать `url(...)` из значения css-свойства случайно не надо? Или и так работает?

Comment: @andreymal Да, надо.

Comment: @Igor извините как вывести за пределы переменные width и height - по тому что когда я их вызываю после всего этого - то они undefined

Comment: @dantelol Изменил. Но они не будут назначены, пока не выполнится `onload`.

Answer (score 1):

Почти универсальная функция на промисе (без jQuery, ES6+):

```js
getImgDimensions('.myuclick').then(d => console.log('background-image:', d));

(async () => {
  const imgd = await getImgDimensions('#foo');
  console.log('src:', imgd);
})();


function getImgDimensions(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (!el) reject(new Error('Element not found'));
    let src;
    if (el.src) {
      src = el.src;
    } else {
      const bgi = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundImage;
      src = (bgi.match(/url\(['"]?([^'")]+)/i) || [0, ''])[1];
    }
    if (!src) reject(new Error('No image found'));
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      resolve({ width: this.naturalWidth, height: this.naturalHeight });
      img = null;
    };
    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error('Error fetching image ' + src));
    img.src = src;
  });
}
```

```css
html, body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.myuclick, #foo { display: inline-block; width: 45%; min-height: 25vw; }
```

```html
<div class="myuclick"
  style="background: center/cover no-repeat url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1043/5184/3456.jpg);"
></div>
<img id="foo" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/1280/720.jpg" alt="">
```

"Почти" - потому что если у img-элемента будет изображение и в `src` и в `background-image`, функция вернет только размеры картинки в `src` (решаемо, но вряд ли нужно).